# jQuery: Class is added but margin-top style is ignored

Tags: jquery, css

I'm toggling a class on an element when hovered, the class is added just fine but `margin-top` seems to just get ignored. How do I get the `margin-top` style to work correctly? [My Code is Here @ jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HJTqN/). Code is just a snippet.

CSS:

```
#nav ul {
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
}
#nav li {
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-right:50px;
}
.hover {
    background-color: red;
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$('#nav ul a li').hover(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('hover');
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="nav">
    <ul>    <a href="">
                <li>

                    <h3>title</h3>
                    <p>description.</p>
                </li>
            </a>
    <a href="">
                <li>
                    <h3>title</h3>
                    <p>description.</p>
                </li>
            </a>
    <a href="">
                <li>
                    <h3>title</h3>
                    <p>description.</p>
                </li>
            </a>

    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Your HTML structure is incorrect `ul > a > li`. You cannot have `a` tag inside `ul`. `ul` can only have `li` elements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a css **specificity** issue, just add `#nav li` before the .hover, see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HJTqN/4/)

The selector `#nav li` is more precise hence `.hover` gets overwritten.

Answer (score 5):

Try using this instead:

```
#nav li.hover{
    background-color: red;
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```

The problem was that your CSS selector wasn't specific enough so `margin-top: 100px;` was being overruled by `margin-top: 0;`.

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth explanation as to the reason why its not working.

Answer (score 3):

your other style is more specific, change `.hover` to `#nav li.hover`

Answer (score 2):

```
#nav ul a li.hover {
    background-color: red;
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```

Please, read about priorities in styles [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cascading_Style_Sheets#CSS_Priority_scheme_.28highest_to_lowest.29)

Answer (score 2):

This is due to CSS Specificity. http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/

You have style set to `#nav li` which will take importance over reference to just a class.

P.s. Avoid using `!important`

Answer (score 1):

Here working e.g.

http://jsfiddle.net/HJTqN/10/
instead of just using .hover use

```
#nav .hover
```

as you have used #nav li to define style previously.

Answer (score 0):

Your `margin-top` is not being applied because your `.hover` class has far less [specificity](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) than the original styling of your list items (which use an ID instead). [Check this out](http://www.stuffandnonsense.co.uk/archives/images/specificitywars-05v2.jpg) for a handy (geeky) chart.

One solution would be to change your CSS to use IDs in both places (as @Alex suggests), or even over-ride with something like `!important`, but neither of those are a viable long-term solution.*

The best thing to do would be to re-factor your CSS to *only* use classes. There's also no need to use jQuery for hover styling if that's all you're trying to achieve. Finally, as @Vega points out, your `ul` can only have `li` items as immediate children. That leaves you [with this](http://jsfiddle.net/cherryflavourpez/gcEza/):

```
.nav ul {
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
}
.nav li a {
    display: block;
    height:100px;
}
.nav li {
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-right:50px;
}
.nav li:hover {
    background-color: red;
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```

and the amended HTML:

```
<div class="nav" id="nav">
    <ul>    
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <h3>title</h3>
                <p>description.</p>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <h3>title</h3>
                <p>description.</p>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <h3>title</h3>
                <p>description.</p>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

* You could argue for using IDs here, but that makes your `.hover` class only usable in this one instance. Using classes alone will make your life easier. Of course, if you amend to use a `:hover` pseudo-class instead then the point becomes moot.

Answer (score -1):

```
please use different class name instead of hover to "hover1".

may be class name  conflict with hover property
```

Comment: This won't cause a problem.